# Use NSLog print variable,why add a nil?

Tags: ios, nslog

```
NSString* name = @"abc";

NSLog(name,nil);
```

who can tell me ,why add a nil?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of `NSLog` is `void NSLog (NSString *format, ...);`.

So the first argument is rather a format instead of a literal string. The second (and all following) arguments are the substitution values for the format string.

You should not replace the format string with the string you want to log. If your string contains format specifiers like `%d` `NSLog` will try to replace them but will fail to do so as you have not entered a substitution.

You should always log with `NSLog(@"%@", string)` when you want to log `string`.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to print a `NSString` using `NSLog` is `NSLog(@"%@", name);`.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet if `someString` contains a special character like `%s`, `NSLog` will expect another argument. If that argument is not present, your app will crash.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet: XCode will give you a warning: `Format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)`. That's because `someString` can contain some format specifiers inside, and `NSLog` will fail to handle them.

Answer (score 0):

That's not at all necessary, but `NSLog` expects a const NSString:

```
NSLog(@"%@", name);
```

although, as long as there are no special flags like `%p`, `%d`, `%s`, `%@`, etc.

```
NSLog(myString);
```

will also work.